# Изменить имя сервера в сетевой папке

Tags: windows, сеть

У меня есть установочный бинарник. У него внутри где-то жестко зашита инструкция взять часть файлов из сетевой папки. Причем там, вероятно, сервер указан именно по имени, а не по ip

```
\\server\dir1\dir2\...\conf
```

Я могу подключиться к серверу с нужными фалами, но он под немного другим именем

```
\\server.a.bit.more.name\dir1\...
```

Из за этого бинарник не хочет нормально работать. Можно как-нибудь сделать в сетевой папке символическую ссылку или что-то такое, что б перенаправить бинарник на нужный сервер, не копаясь во внутренностях бинарника?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, так сделать нельзя.

Но вы можете отредактировать файл hosts (на винде он лежит в %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, а линуксе - в /etc/hosts) чтобы назначить произвольному имени произвольный ip-адрес. Открывается он любым текстовым редактором (на винде Блокнот подойдет, только запускайте его с привилегиями администратора).

По умолчанию там уже прописан адрес для localhost, для вашего сервера делайте по аналогии.

Только отключите антивирус перед редактированием - они любят блокировать редактирование этого файла (и не зря).

Answer (score 0):

Временно запишите соответствие в файл HOSTS прописанного в бинарнике имени и IP-адреса реального сервера.

Только не забудьте потом удалить...

Comment: Можно и не удалять, если адрес сервера постоянный.

Comment: Если сервер с таким именем в сети отсутствует (и гарантированно не появится в будущем) - да, можно оставить. Если же он есть, и только на время установки надо перенаправить - то удалять обязательно. Ну а если по окончании установки обращения выполняются по адресу или сконфигурированному имени - какой смысл держать неправильное соответствие?